# Converting Videos for iPhone/iPad (mp4)

Tags: iphone, ipad, video

I know this isn't quite a programming question but it's very closely related to iPhone/iPad development.

What's a good software (preferably with a GUI) for converting videos to iPhone/iPad compatible **mp4s**? My videos are mostly `mpg, avi, mov`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handbrake will do a great job, its free, its open source, and it is on Windows, Linux, and Macintosh.

I know it takes file inputs from any source on Windows (I'm not sure on Mac, but I'm pretty sure its the same on Mac).

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, cheers @Ajay. Accepting your answer because you were first.

Answer (score 2):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is my favorite tool for this job. Free and Multiplatform.

Integrates with all of the appropriate preset for iPhone / iPod / iPhone 4

Answer (score 1):

Just for note: I use ffmpeg library to convert all my media. Yes, it doesn't have UI but it supports probably almost all the video/audio formats you need + it's very easy to use it with scripts when you want to convert a big amount of media.

Comment: Cheers @Max, do you know if ffmpeg can run on the device itself?

Comment: yes, without any problems. you just need to cross-compile it for arm processors. check this out https://github.com/gabriel/ffmpeg-iphone-build